# Successful use of SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilEventNotified(func, eventName) in CSOM/JSOM?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, csom, sharepoint-jsom

I have used the SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(func, depScriptFileName) quite a bit in my JSOM (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff411788(v=office.14).aspx). Has anybody out there used SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilEventNotified(func, eventName) (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff410354(v=office.14).aspx) successfully? For eventName is it as something as simple as "click"? I have searched the web but haven't found anything useful. Any Feedback appreciated.

Comment: It is used to detect a SharePoint event ("_spEventWebPartAdderReady") in the answer to this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22318388/sp-ribbon-webpartcomponent-getwebpartadder-returns-undefined

Comment: Thanks Thriggle, good answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically the difference between those functions that in first case the name of the file from client library is specified, for example `sp.js` (parameter `depScriptFileName`). In the latter case the event name should be specified, for example `"sp.scriptloaded-sp.js"` ( parameter `eventName`)

Here is the declaration for [`SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilEventNotified(func, eventName)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff410354(v=office.14).aspx) from SharePoint Client library `init.js`:

```
function ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(func, depScriptFileName) {
    depScriptFileName = depScriptFileName.toLowerCase();
    var eventName = "sp.scriptloaded-" + depScriptFileName;

    return ExecuteOrDelayUntilEventNotified(func, eventName);
}
```

**About event names**

The list of event names is stored in global variable called `g_ExecuteOrWaitJobs`. For every SharePoint Client library file is used a predefined event name, for example for a file `sp.clienttemplates.js` the corresponding event name is `sp.scriptloaded-clienttemplates.js`

---

Lets demonstrate how to utilize both [`SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(func, depScriptFileName)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff411788(v=office.14).aspx) and [`SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilEventNotified(func, eventName)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff410354(v=office.14).aspx) functions.

For that purposes let's introduce a simple example that prints `SP.Web` Title property:

```
function printWebInfo(){
      var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
      var web = ctx.get_web();
      ctx.load(web,'Title'); 
      ctx.executeQueryAsync(
         function(){
            console.log(web.get_title());
         },
         function(sender,args){
            console.log(args.get_message()); 
         });
}
```

In the following example

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(printWebInfo, "sp.js");
```

`printWebInfo` function will be invoked once SharePoint Client library `sp.js` is loaded.

The same example that utilizes [`SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilEventNotified(func, eventName)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff410354(v=office.14).aspx) will look like this:

```
var eventName = "sp.scriptloaded-sp.js";
ExecuteOrDelayUntilEventNotified(printWebInfo,eventName);
```

where `"sp.scriptloaded-sp.js"` event name is used to determine whether `sp.js` library is loaded or not.

Comment: Thanks Vadim for the post,  I was able to look into all the events in the g_ExecuteOrWaitJobs and see all of the events and good usage example